# How to use method in the name of variable?

Tags: java, variables, for-loop, methods

I have to create a few variables like: "n23, n4, n18...".
So, they consist of two parts: letter "n" and a number witch I want to get from my method for generating random numbers(rand()).

Something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    int n*here_must_be_random_number_got_from_my_method*;
}
```

Is it possible to do something similar?

Comment: You cannot. Use an array, map, or list.

Comment: Why are you creating variables at runtime? Variables are part of the class definition, not part of the state of the object at runtime.

Comment: This looks a lot like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You can use [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) to do this, which is a dynamic language for Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is no script language.

All identifiers, which means all package names, type names, method names, field names and variables, must be specified at compile time. So there is no way to concatenate your variable names based on values calculated at runtime.

BUT!

You do not even need to. Just use a `java.util.Map`. Instead of doing

```
int n*here_must_be_random_number_got_from_my_method* = *whatever_it_is_you_want_to_put_here*;
```

you can instead do

```
Map<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

once, then put values inside the map like so:

```
myMap.put(*here_must_be_random_number_got_from_my_method*, *whatever_it_is_you_want_to_put_here*);
```

and get it back like so:

```
myMap.get(*here_must_be_random_number_got_from_my_method*);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but presumably you want to *refer* to these later, and if you were intending to refer to `n123`, then you can hopefully refer to them as `n[123]` instead. If that's the case, then you can use a java array, perhaps like this:

```
private int[] n = new int[999];

void populate() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        n[here_must_be_random_number_got_from_my_method] = something;
    }
}
```

Note that java doesn't do sparse arrays, so the size of your array needs to be as large as the largest random number. If this us large, consider using a map as per Jan's answer.

Comment: Assuming he does not really have all numbers between 0 and 999, this would be a waste of resources *as well as* a semantic violation. Looking up a value based on a key is a `Map`s job, not an arrays.

Comment: @jan yes. I had considered that. Noted in answer with a pointer to your answer